# put Leadbolt on Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, leadbolt

i have using leadbolt on my game. i have no problem with load ads on my main menu page because its using android activity. but i can't load the ads when i'm on the other page which is using andengine activity (baseGameActivity). here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadComplete() 
{
  // load ads
  myController = new AdController(this, "388910311");
  myController.loadAd();
}
```

i'm concern about someone answer "Cant pass in application context for Ads, you need to pass in the Activity." but he doesn't mention how to send this activity value or where i must put this code so my ads is loaded well.

Answer (score 0):

```java
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "388910311");
        myController.loadAd();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply. i put your code and get two errors. mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this); <- this need only one parameters. and frameLayout.addView(myController, adViewLayoutParams); <- myContrroller must a View.

Comment: still get error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: i put your code at onLoadComplete and still get error : java.lang.NullPointerException